# jQuery scrollTop in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I am using jQuery in an attempt to scroll to the #target div when the #selector is clicked.  The two elements are in seperate Bootstrap Tab Panels / Tab Panes.

It seems I am unable to get the scroll effect to work when the #target is outside the #selector's parent Panel/Pane.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation" class="active">
    <a href="#home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"></a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation">
    <a href="#profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"></a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation">
    <a href="#messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"></a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation">
    <a href="#settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"></a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">

  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">
    <div id="selector"></div>
  </div>

  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">
    <div id="target"></div>
  </div>

  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="messages">...</div>

  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="settings">...</div>
</div>
```

Any ideas as to how I can achieve the scrollTop effect in a different tab? Am i getting hung up on the Bootstrap CSS? Alternative suggestions?  Thanks for your time.

Heres the JS, the first function just changes tabs based on the selected element's href.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
    var target = this.href.split('#');
    $('.nav a').filter('a[href="#' + target[1] + '"]').tab('show');
  })
  $('#selector').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body, nav').delay(500).animate({
      scrollTop: $("#target").offset().top
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

Comment: Please explain more i can't really understand what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [.closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest)(which gets the parent) get the tab in which the `#target` div is placed. Then open that tab. Then scroll to top using animate.

Instead of using `.delay()` I used setTimeout because the animate will happen before the tab is opened which is not required.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
    var target = this.href.split('#');
    showTab(target[1]);
  });
  $('#selector').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $('#target').closest('.tab-pane').attr('id');
    showTab(target);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('html, body, nav').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#target").offset().top
      }, 500);
    }, 500);
  });
});

function showTab(target) {
  $('.nav a').filter('a[href="#' + target + '"]').tab('show');
}
```

Here is a demo **http://jsbin.com/xomafe/edit?html,js,output**

Hope this helps