# How to set scrollTop inside a bootstrap tab

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, scrolltop

```js
 $('#s5').on('click', function (event) {
     $('.nav-tabs a[href="#listcontent"]').tab('show');
     $('#side').animate({
         scrollTop: $('#stage5').offset().top
     }, 2000);
 });
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
.fill {
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}
.container-side {
    padding: 10px 0 10px 15px;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.tab-content {
    overflow: auto;
    height: calc(100vh - 202px);
    /* 100vh = 100% height of viewport. 182px = 100px (#header) + 20px (.container-side) + 42px  (.nav-tabs) + 40px (#footer) */
    height: -webkit-calc(100vh - 202px);
    height: -moz-calc(100vh - 202px);
}
.container-side ul {
    margin-right: 15px;
}
.fixheight {
    min-height: 200px;
}
#sidecontent {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: calc(100vh - 197px);
    /* 100vh = 100% height of viewport. 197px = 192px (.tab-content) + 5px */
    height: -webkit-calc(100vh - 207px);
    height: -moz-calc(100vh - 207px);
}
body {
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid fill">
    <div class="row-fluid fill">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-5 container-side">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#content" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Content</a>

                </li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#listcontent" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">listcontent</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
            <div id="side" class="tab-content">
                <div id="content" class="container-fluid tab-pane fade in active">
                    <h2>Route 1</h2>

                    <div>Cyprum itidem insulam procul a continenti discretam et portuosam inter municipia crebra urbes duae faciunt claram Salamis et Paphus.</div>
                </div>
                <div id="listcontent" class="container-fluid tab-pane fade">
                    <div id="stage1" class="fixheight">
                         <h2>Stage 1</h2>

                    </div>
                    <div id="stage2" class="fixheight">
                         <h2>Stage 2</h2>

                    </div>
                    <div id="stage3" class="fixheight">
                         <h2>Stage 3</h2>

                    </div>
                    <div id="stage4" class="fixheight">
                         <h2>Stage 4</h2>

                    </div>
                    <div id="stage5" class="fixheight">
                         <h2>Stage 5</h2>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7 col-md-7 container-map">
            <div id="map">
                <div id="s5">stage5</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="sidebar"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the jsfidle code : http://jsfiddle.net/BrunoD/fn3L0v20/1/

After a click on `stage5` link, I change the tab to `listcontent` tab and then i would like that the scroll bar positioned on `stage5` div inside the `listcontent` div

Unfortunately the position of the scroll bar is not moved.

Comment: I have replaced   $('#listcontent').animate({  by  $('#listcontent').animate({  this seems better. Now it works when the listcontent tab is activated. So how could first activate the tab and then move the scrollbar to stage position.

Answer (score 0):

You can use event for first tab change.

```
$("#map a").on('click', function(event) {
// Prevent default anchor click behavior
event.preventDefault();
var hash = this.hash;

if (window.location.hash) {
    window.location.hash = hash;
}

$tab = $('#listcontentA');
$tab.tab('show');

$tab.on('shown.bs.tab', function () {
    window.location.hash = hash;
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fn3L0v20/3/

Is that what you need?

Comment: Thanks. But this solution uses anchors and the scroolbar change is not really smoothy. I try to have no anchors and a smooth scroll.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $('#map #s1').on('click', function(event) {
  var atab = $('.nav-tabs .active').text();
  if (atab=='listcontent') $('#side').animate({scrollTop: $('#stage1').position().top}, 2000);
  else {
   $('.nav-tabs a[href="#listcontent"]').tab('show').on('shown.bs.tab', function () {
    $('#side').animate({scrollTop: $('#stage1').position().top}, 2000);
   });
  }
    });
 $('#map #s3').on('click', function(event) {
  var atab = $('.nav-tabs .active').text();
  if (atab=='listcontent') $('#side').animate({scrollTop: $('#stage3').position().top}, 2000);
  else {
   $('.nav-tabs a[href="#listcontent"]').tab('show').on('shown.bs.tab', function () {
    $('#side').animate({scrollTop: $('#stage3').position().top}, 2000);
   });
  }
    });
 $('#map #s5').on('click', function(event) {
  var atab = $('.nav-tabs .active').text();
  if (atab=='listcontent') $('#side').animate({scrollTop: $('#stage5').position().top}, 2000);
  else {
   $('.nav-tabs a[href="#listcontent"]').tab('show').on('shown.bs.tab', function () {
    $('#side').animate({scrollTop: $('#stage5').position().top}, 2000);
   });
  }
    });
```

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.fill {  
 padding: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}

.container-side {  
 padding: 10px 0 10px 15px;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.tab-content {
 overflow: auto;  
 height: calc(100vh - 202px); /* 100vh = 100% height of viewport. 182px = 100px (#header) + 20px (.container-side) + 42px  (.nav-tabs) + 40px (#footer) */
 height: -webkit-calc(100vh - 202px);
 height: -moz-calc(100vh - 202px);
}

.container-side ul {
 margin-right: 15px;
}

.fixheight {
 min-height: 200px;
}

#sidecontent {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
 height: calc(100vh - 197px); /* 100vh = 100% height of viewport. 197px = 192px (.tab-content) + 5px */
 height: -webkit-calc(100vh - 207px);
 height: -moz-calc(100vh - 207px);
}

body {
 padding-top: 100px;
 padding-bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid fill">
 <div class="row-fluid fill">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-5 container-side">
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#content" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Content</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#listcontent" data-toggle="tab" id="listcontentA" role="tab">listcontent</a></li>
   </ul>
   <div id="side" class="tab-content">
    <div id="content" class="container-fluid tab-pane fade in active">
     <h2>Route 1</h2>
     <div>
 Cyprum itidem insulam procul a continenti discretam et portuosam inter municipia crebra urbes duae faciunt claram Salamis et Paphus.    
     </div>
    </div>
    <div id="listcontent" class="container-fluid tab-pane fade">
     <div id="stage1" class="fixheight"><h2>Stage 1</h2></div>
     <div id="stage2" class="fixheight"><h2>Stage 2</h2></div>
     <div id="stage3" class="fixheight"><h2>Stage 3</h2></div>
     <div id="stage4" class="fixheight"><h2>Stage 4</h2></div>
     <div id="stage5" class="fixheight"><h2>Stage 5</h2></div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7 col-md-7 container-map">
   <div id="map">
    <div id="s1">stage1</div>
    <div id="s3">stage3</div>
    <div id="s5">stage5</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="sidebar"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

$('.nav-tabs .active').text();  provides the active tab. If listcontent is not activated, we need to wait that the tab is activated before to move the scroolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is not done directly by setting scrollTop on the tab div.
The following answers gives a working solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31394286/2143734

for your case, I would do like that :

```
$('html, body, nav').animate({
  scrollTop: $("#your-div").prop('scrollHeight')
}, 500);
```